# #! in url makes webpage act odd

Tags: php, html, wordpress, url

I'm working on a website through wordpress, where I have an image, which have a link to a subsite. If I just go directly to the subsite, the site is render as I want it to (it uses a gallery plugin), but once it go to the subsite by the link, the plugin acts really funny. I think it might have something to do with the fact that the site i'm linking from contains #! in the url, which gets passed onto the next site. So it would go from something like this www.hello.com/#!/test/ and then goes to this site www.hello.com/#!/test/link/, but my site is at www.hello.com/test/link. Anybody know what #! does in a url and how to remove it?

Answer (score 4):

`#!` is a shebang, and (in the context of a URL) it's basically used to tell search engines that they can access the same file as the one shown by the URL, by accessing the path shown after the shebang.

Since it's only used in AJAX-based sites, and even then only if you tell it to be, then you should just be able to delete the code that uses it...